# Is there a free product configuration software framework?

Tags: gratis, ecommerce, recommendation-engine

I imagine the following features (maybe my request can be fulfilled with a combination of existing free frameworks):

- specification of configuration combinations in a logic (markup) language
- GUI elements with binding to the specification in logic language
- handling of commonly used workflows strong integration with an e-commerce platform (displaying available parts based on storage management, delivery overtimes for individual components)
- recommendations based on current configuration